# How to create an IPA for MDM system withouth re-signing IPA?

Tags: app-store, distribution, ipa, mdm

I'm working with a client and they use the MDM system (Workspace ONE) they want to test my app (mostly AppConfig)  before I upload the IPA to the app store where ultimately they can grab from there into the MDM system and distribute it to their users. For some reason, they don't want to have an ad-hoc build/Enterprise distribution (I suggested the re-sign option, but they declined). Anyway, they ask me for an IPA file that I use for AppStore and I provided them but they say the system returned an error saying " This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified"

I wonder what could be the right approach to release the IPA file for the MDM system for testing? I don't think there is another approach for app distribution other than re-signing in-house distribution build.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cam